# Truncating Dropdown Item

Tags: jquery, concatenation, truncate, html.dropdownlistfor

I've got this area of a website I'm working on with several dropdown lists that relate to each other. On the 3rd list I'm trying to truncate item that is selected and concatenate an ellipsis at the end of it with jQuery. I've tried several solutions but I'm not having any luck. Can anyone please tell me what I'm missing here?

Here's what I'm working with:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>       
</head>
<body>
<div class="search-dtls">
    <h3>Select Book</h3>
    <div class="searh-field">
        <select class="select" id="cont" name="cont">
            <option>Book Language</option>
            <option value="1">English</option>
            <option value="5">Spanish</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="searh-field">
        <select class="select" id="cont2" name="cont">
            <option selected="selected">Year Published</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="searh-field">
        <select class="select" id="cont3" name="cont">
            <option selected="selected">Select Book</option>
            <option value="234">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </option>
            <option value="804">Fusce efficitur fermentum nibh ac congue nulla a urna at massa cursus cursus.</option>
            <option value="224">Lorem ut vulputate facilisis, est nibh ullamcorper turpis, a sodales dui nisi vel odio.</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="search" value="Start Your search">
</div>
<script>

    var len = 30;
    var p = $('#cont3 option');

    p.each(function(){
        if(p.length > len) {
            console.log("item");
        }
    });

</script>
</body>
```

I feel like I'm close but my conditional is screwed up. I know I'm selecting the correct elements because when I put `console.log("item");` outside of the 'if' statement I see "item" printed 4 times to the console. If I replace p = p.substring(0, len) + "..."; with console.log("item"); it doesn't print anything.

So I guess what I need to know is:
 
1) How go get my 'if' statement working properly, and
2) how would you have this effect after the option is selected? So when you see the options they're full text but the selected text is truncated with the ellipsis appended on?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You're getting ALL the options, rather than just one

```
var len = 30;
$('#cont3 option').each(function(index, value) {
     if(this.text.length > len) {
        this.text = this.text.substring(0, len) + '...';
    }
});
```

Based on your question below - I think that it'd be more beneficial to just truncate them all anyways. The version below will change the text on `change` but will not replace it with the old text once it's not highlighted (selected) anymore. Nonetheless -

change to `change` function

```
 $('#cont3').change(function () {
     var text = $(this).text();
     if(text.length > len) {
        $(this).text() = text.substring(0, len) + '...';
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited my question at the bottom to make it a little more specific. I'm actually hoping to only do this to the selected option and not all of the options in the dropdown. So someone picks the 1st option it's truncated when showing as selected and so on with each of the others.